# Form action in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, php-5.3, laravel-routing

I have a problem with my form in laravel,
So my project structure is:

```
controllers/
       administration/
            NewsController.php
```

in NewsController I have a method call : postCreate():

```
 public function postCreate(){
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), \News::$rules);
    if($validator->passes()){
        $news = new \News();
        $news->title = Input::get('title');
        $news->content = Input::get('content');
        $news->author = Input::get('author');
        $news->type = Input::get('type');

        $image = Input::file('file');
        $filename = time().".".$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $path = public_path('content/images/' . $filename);
        Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(468,249)->save($path);
        $news->image = 'content/images/'.$filename;
        $news->save();

        return Redirect::to('/administration/news/add')
            ->with('message','Succes');
    }
    return Redirect::to('/administration/news/add')
        ->with('message','Error')
        ->withErrors($validator)
        ->withInput();
}
```

My form have action :

```
{{ Form::open(array('url'=>'administration/news/create', 'files'=>true)) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

My route:

```
Route::post('/administration/news/create', array('uses'=>'App\Controllers\Administration \NewsController@postCreate'));
```

But when I submit I get an error:

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException

I don't understand where is my problem.

Comment: run php artisan routes to see if each of the routes have been declared properly.

Comment: It's better to send a form to an action. That way Laravel will automaticaly set the form to `post` or `get`.

Comment: what namespace you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small adjustment.... forget manually creating addresses.

**In routes.php:**

```
Route::post('/administration/news/create', 
          array('uses'=>'App\Controllers\Administration\NewsController@postCreate',
                 'as' => 'news.post.create'));
```

**In View:**

```
{{ Form::open(array('url'=>route('news.post.create'), 'files'=>true)) }}
```

no need to memorise any of those addresses.

Answer (score 1):

You have a whitespace in your code. Your route should be:

```
Route::post('/administration/news/create', array('uses'=>'App\Controllers\Administration\NewsController@postCreate'));
```

Besides that, altough laravel gives you standard a POST action, its always better to add a POST action to your form.

```
'method' => 'post'
```